# How to construct a location?

Tags: location, rascal

I have a simple question.

Suppose I have a location

```
 loc l = |file:////Users/steven/tst.txt|;
```

and I want to make it more detailled, by selecting line 5 - 10. How do I do that?

Simply stating

```
l.begin.line = 5; l.begin.column = 0;
```

goes wrong.

So, I have the following questions:

1. How can I set `l.begin.line` and `l.begin.column`?
2. How can I easily detect the last column of line 10?
3. How can I set `l.offset` and `l.length` accordingly in an easy way?
4. Were can I find the Rascal module that defines locations? (The tutorial suggests me to look in the library between ListRelation and Map, but that doesn't help)

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. The rule for source locations is that if you provide position information within a file and you want to provide line and column information, then offset/length is also required, like so:

```
rascal>a = |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|;
loc: |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|
rascal>b = a(0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>);
loc: |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|(0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>)
```

You could also type it in directly in the literal:

```
rascal>a = |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|(0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>);
loc: |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|(0,10,<2,0>,<4,10>)
```

Or without the line/column information:

```
rascal>a = |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|(0,10);
loc: |file:///Users/steven/tst.txt|(0,10)
```

It's just not possible to create a location without offset/length en with line/column information. To get the information necessary to create a full `loc` you usually need access to the contents of the file.

PS: we count unicode characters in the files, not bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your answer, based on your answer I could construct the function that I needed, namely a function that constructs a location from a file and a start- and end-linenumber.

The `eol=2` is detected from locations that were constructed by Rascal.

Could you please correct it if you see a flaw?

```
public loc getFragment(loc f, int startLine, int endLine) {

    loc fragment = |file:///null|;
    int eol = 2;

    if (exists(f)) {
        int offset = 0;
        int len = 0;
        int i = 0;
        int endCol = 0;
        for (str line <- readFileLines(f)) {
            i += 1;
            if (i < startLine) {
                offset += size(line) + eol;
            } else if (i <= endLine) {
                len += size(line);
                if (i == endLine) {
                    endCol = size(line);
                } else {
                    len += eol;
                }
            }
        }
        fragment = f(offset,len,<startLine,0>,<endLine,endCol>);
    } 
    return fragment;
}
```